# Open modal AND non-modal

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

First off: Im a total Winform newbie... but im trying :)

My customer wants something like this:

Simple scenario:
1) From my Main-form a non-modal dialog is opened (for reading and taking notes).
2) From my Main-form a modal dialog is opened.
3) The new modal dialog must not prevent the non-modal dialog from getting focus.

My question:
Is this possible? And if so: How?

Regards
Smoller - WinForm newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible.  The modal dialog will be invoked on the main UI thread and will block the thread until it is closed.

You would be better off with two non-modal dialogs for this, and just put the second one higher up the Z order so it show in front of the first.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response ... Though the answer was not what I hoped :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly possible the way you describe it but you can use the Owner property of the forms to get close to the behaviour you desire.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx

From your main form you want to spawn new forms by setting the Ower property like this:

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.Owner = this; // assuming this is your main form
form.Show();
```

Or you can simply pass the owner as a parameter to the Show method:

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.Show(this);
```

The reason this might help is because setting the Owner provides the following behaviour (from the documentation).

> Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is selected.

But you can have more than one child form of your main window, unlike modal dialogs.